# complex Queries in kibana or quering for different values of a single field type

Tags: kibana

I am new to Kibana. I have successfully  installed Logstash ,Elasticsearch and Kibana. All the links or documents i read have simple query syntax like search by text,by typing phrase or putting logical operators .but all this is so basic.
How can we query in detail.for example  i have logs of my magento store and the logs have time stamp,product ID and the action that is the product is purchased or viewed or removed like that.

I imported these logs in kibana via logstash.

Now i want to query logs for the action field not different fields.When i query the logs it returns me logs that have added action and logs that have  remove action.The query is "added" OR "removed" when i do "added" AND "removed" there are no logs given because these both words are of same field type and kibana does not allow this it returns zero records because any particular log cant have two valuesin the action field that is product added and removed.I need to know the product which is added and removed  the most by people and do a visualization of that.

please suggest if there are any tutorial for studying kibana lik, how to configure it learn to write complex queries

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse your logs in Logstash to multiple fields. 
As your requirement, say add field-"Action" and field "Product".

In the Kibana you can add Table with terms set to "Product" field. 
So, when you search for "Added", the table will show out all the product with Added action.

Comment: yaa i am doing that only... i have parsed the logs via logstash and created a field action which has multiple values like added or removed.. but i want to get those logs.. or say those product ids which are in added action and removes action

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to match two disparate search terms in the SAME field using logical operators.  For example, a field called 'product_comments' has value 'residential plumbing bathroom sink", and I want "residential" AND "sink" to match.

The documentation here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#AND says this is possible, just as OP originally tried.

Using Kibana 5.1.1 I found that logical operator is case sensitive:
"residential" and "sink" matched documents with the word 'and' in it, but
"residential" AND "sink" worked as expected

Comment: actually now I see I misunderstood OP question.  anyway, maybe this info will be helpful